# can we efficiently use ros in ubuntu, installed in flash drive?

Tags: ros, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello , can we efficiently use ros in ubuntu, installed in flash drive ? i installed it using virtual box but it's  slow in that so i want to find a better alternative so can we use it in flash drive installed ubuntu efficiently.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253841/can-we-efficiently-use-ros-in-ubuntu,-installed-in-flash-drive-?/) by [rishabh4011](https://answers.ros.org/users/29260/rishabh4011/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pallavbakshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28889/pallavbakshi/) on 2017-02-05**:
I did the same but didn't work out that well. Ubuntun reported "ran out of virtual memory" each time I tried to install heavier packagaes - openCV, etc. Instead, create a partition and dual boot Ubuntu.

**Comment by [rishabh4011](https://answers.ros.org/users/29260/rishabh4011/) on 2017-02-05**:
thanks.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, that is definitely possible.

Two things to keep in mind if you want to do this:

1. use a usb stick / flash drive with good read/write performance: some of the more recent USB3 sticks reach (sequential) read speeds of everal tens of MB/sec and have low access latencies. Both are important.
2. use a sufficiently large drive: depending on what you are going to do, packages can take up quite some space, even without considering some of the requirements for data storage (ie: maps, rosbags, etc). This is the same with a regular hdd/sdd, but definitely something to keep in mind.

And it might not be too much of a problem (anymore, or you just don't care), but all flash media have a limited nr of write-cycles. Running an OS (with `/tmp` and potentially swap space) on a flash drive is a good way to exhaust those quickly (wear levelling will help significantly though).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on 2017-02-05**:
As a companion comment,when  running ROS + Ubuntu on a Raspberry Pi the SD card is not different than a USB memory stick. As long as the solid state memory storage is fast, it works well. Running with RAM based temp storage makes a significant improvement.